# Julia Plot in Python (a short recode help)

Tags: python, python-requests, julia

I write a code to simulate geometry process for my work and plot it in Julia Programming Language as [Here](https://julialang.org/) as follows:

```
using StatsBase, Distributions, Plots; pyplot()

function rouletteSpins(p)
    x = 0
    while true
        x += 1
        if rand() < p
            return x
        end
    end
end

 p, xGrid, N = 18/37, 1:7, 10^6

 mcEstimate = counts([rouletteSpins(p) for _ in 1:N],xGrid)/N

 gDist = Geometric(p)
 gPmf = [pdf(gDist,x-1) for x in xGrid]

plot(xGrid, mcEstimate, line=:stem, marker=:circle,
    c=:blue, ms=10, msw=0, lw=4, label="MC estimate")
plot!( xGrid, gPmf, line=:stem, marker=:xcross,
    c=:red, ms=6, msw=0, lw=2, label="PMF",
    ylims=(0,0.5), xlabel="x", ylabel="Probability")
```

to plot:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBgC2.png)

I want to recode it to Python in-order to use it and plug it to another part of my research code. my objective is try to plot the same chart and not expert in Python.

Comment: Would you post some of your Python research? That would help get an idea of where you want to go with this.

Comment: Use can also use PyJulia to call your julia function from within Python..